# Using Map arguments in constructor

Tags: java

I have a class, `Student` with this constructor.

```
 public Student(String name, int age, Map<String, Integer> grades) {
    this.setName(name);
    this.setAge(age);
    this.setGrades(grades);
 }
```

when creating a Student object, how do I pass the Map argument in the constructor?

What am looking for is something similar to this:

```
List<Student> roster = new ArrayList<>();
roster.add(new Student("Ann Droid", 145, Arrays.asList(96, 78)));
```

If I had this constructor:

```
public Student(String name, int age, List<Integer> grades) {
    this.setName(name);
    this.setAge(age);
    this.setGrades(grades);
 }
```

Comment: Java does not support a map literal ;( And I know of no helper function that does what you want like `Array.asList`.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to pass the argument "for testing" you could consider sending a mock. Not sure I would do it for a simple Map though, just something to consider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vanilla flavor plain Java doesn't have anything for Maps as `Arrays.asList()`.  So you will have to initialize the `Map` over several line of code like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> grades = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
grades.put("English", 90);
roster.add(new Student("Ann Droid", 145, grades);
```

However, with Google's Guava you can do this:

```
Map<String, Integer> grades = ImmutableMap.of("English", 90);
```

Comment: [ImmutableMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html)

Answer (score 3):

It can't be done with a one liner.

```
Map<String,Integer> grades = new HashMap<>();
grades.put("Math", 100);
roster.add(new Student("Ann Droid", 145, grades));
```

Comment: Well it can, if you make a utility vararg function as in `Maps.map("Math", 100, "Physics", 70)`

Comment: @WouterLievens Well, I can argue that writing such a utility requires more than one line of code, so it still won't be a one liner :)

Comment: @WouterLievens Guava's `ImmutableMap` is essentially what are you are referring to here.  It appears to be a one-liner, but behind the scenes the Map is getting initialized.

Comment: Hi @Eran what do you think of the answer from @SanyaLuc? It's a one-liner no?

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu It works, but I wouldn't use anonymous class for the sake of having a one liner. I think it's less readable.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to create a `Map` in a one-liner with Java <= 7 and with the standard JDK. (Well you could technically with a double brace initializer, but it's considered as a bad practice).

In Java 8, you could use the Stream API to achieve this:

```
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

...
new Student("Name", 
            10,
            Stream.of(new SimpleEntry<>("MyString", 1), 
                      new SimpleEntry<>("AnotherString", 2))
                  .collect(toMap(SimpleEntry::getKey, SimpleEntry::getValue)));
```

Now you have to see it if improves readability or not for your use case ;)

Or you could modify your design so that the `Map<String, Integer>` is represented with a `List<Grade>` instead, with each `Grade` having a `String` representing the course and an `Integer` for the Student's mark for this course.

And then you could use `Arrays.asList`:

```
new Student("John", 
            18, 
            Arrays.asList(new Grade("French", 1), new Grade("Math", 5)));
```

Of course you have to ensure uniqueness of the grades.

Comment: Not very far from a map literal ;)

Comment: Just a personal opinion but if I saw that code in a code review, it would die

Comment: The functional programming people are trying to take over Java, and I hope I become a project manager before that happens ^ ^

Comment: @MrSpoon I wish that there is something like `HashMap.of(...)` in the standard JDK... :-)

Comment: You could ensure the uniqueness of the grades by using a Set instead of a List and implementing equals & hashCode in the Grade class, only using the subject name (not the value of the grade).

Answer (score 3):

You can make a utility function yourself. It's not very type-safe, though, because you need to circumvent typing to (ab)use the varags parameter.

```
public class MapExample
{
    public static <K, V> Map<K, V> map(Object... objects)
    {
        Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int n = 0; n < objects.length; n += 2)
        {
            map.put((K)objects[n], (V)objects[n + 1]);
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(map("AAA", 123, "BBB", 456));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not saying it's superior or the best solution, but it works. A good alternative would be to have a generic builder... you can probably do that with generic typesafety.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this option using an [anonymous constructor](https://www.clear.rice.edu/comp310/JavaResources/anon_inner.html)

```
List<Student> roster = new ArrayList<Student>();
roster.add(new Student("Ann Droid", 145, new HashMap<String, Integer>(){{
                                         put("English", 78);
                                         put("Math", 96);
                                         }}));
```

Or you can use [Guava ImmutableMap of()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#of(K,%20V,%20K,%20V)), but this API is limited to five pairs.

```
List<Student> roster = new ArrayList<>();
roster.add(new Student("Ann Droid", 145, ImmutableMap.of("English", 78, "Math", 96);
```

Comment: Works, but you have to change `HashMap<>() {{..` to `HashMap<String, Integer>() {{..`